# Convert Matlab produced string binary to float

Tags: c++, matlab, encoding, binary

I am looking for a correct way to decode a 64-bits binary in C++, encoded in Matlab (which I am not familiar with) with:

```
reshape(dec2bin(typecast(number,'uint8'),8).',1,[])
```

where 'number' is a float number (negative or positive)

produces something like `1100001011000000011100111110111111100001100100101110100000111111`

---

I've tried different approaches to decode the binary, for example:

```
double bitstring_to_double(const char* p)
{
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    for (; *p; ++p)
    {
        x = (x << 1) + (*p - '0');
    }
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, &x, 8);
    return d;
}
```

But I am getting huge values, for example, -1.21694e+118

Comment: Where did you come up with the code to do this conversion?  C++ has no set format for floating point data, but usually it follows IEEE convention.  Unless you have knowledge of what those bits represent, and what format your C++ compiler represents `double` as, then you should first look for a Matlab or other library function to do this work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you mean the conversion in Matlab? I just know that the binaries should correspond to real values between -10 and 10

Comment: This might help: http://www.cprogramto.com/c-program-convert-binary-float/   Why not just display the float in Matlab?

Comment: @Untitled123 same 'big' results

Comment: If Matlab is giving you the same big numbers, then you might need to investigate if the numbers are being generated correctly.

Comment: @Untitled123 I have not tried decoding with Matlab yet

Comment: It's likely that Matlab supports this directly, though I'm not quite sure why you are running dectobin in the first place.

Comment: @Untitled123 Matlab code was written by someone else, I am just using binary results

Comment: This might help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html

Comment: @MocialovBoris `I just know that the binaries should correspond to real values between -10 and 10`  Unless you have written documentation on what each and every bit represents, you can't just come up with code on your own to do this conversion.  So far I have yet to see a breakdown of what each bit and each section of that binary string represents (in terms of floating point).  If you can point to this information, then we can take a look at it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the line `reshape(dec2bin(typecast(..` takes the float value directly

Comment: @MocialovBoris I am referring to this line in your post -- *I've tried different approaches to decode the binary*  -- You shouldn't be guessing here.  You should know up front what those bits represent in terms of floating point, and especially if that `double` represents an IEEE 754 value.  Here is the format of such a double: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format  This is the type of information that you should be looking for if indeed that number represents a typical C++ `double`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you. This makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see the usage of the parameter s anywhere in your function. Assuming that p somehow represents s, this loop is infinite, as you never update *p to consume the last character of s.

Comment: my bad, it is p instead of s. Changed the question